# SSRS DataSource Windows Authentication fails

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a project which uses SharePoint lists as data sources to create the reports. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for this.

I have this real annoying issue at this moment, ie. when I want to edit a dataset I created a while ago and I press 'Query Designer...' in the dataset properties to see all fields from my list I get an error which says that I am unauthorized.

[image]

My DataSource is configured to link to the SharePoint Site Url with Windows Credentials. I have also tried this out for multiple datasets on multiple reports but the error is everywhere.

Because of this I'm also not able to run my reports. They just say "An error occurred during local report processing.".

[image]

I have been working on this project since March and this is the first time this has occurred so I have no idea what might have gone wrong nor how to solve it.

Does anyone know what might cause this error and how to solve it please?

If you have any questions or remarks about my question/problem, please, don't hesitate to leave a comment.

Kind regards

---

EDIT 1:
I have just tried deploying a report that I finished last week and for the first time I got a prompt that asked for my credentials. I haven't even put my credentials anywhere in the project for past authorisation so I have no idea why the project would suddenly need it now...

[image]

---

EDIT 2:

I have just tried changing the DataSource credentials to my own login for the SharePoint Site. If I run the report I get the same error as before but when I go to Query Designer for one of the datasets I get following error:

[image]

---

EDIT 3:

I just restored a back-up I made a couple of weeks ago. I can now run my reports but I still get the Unauthorized error when I try to open a dataset's query designer and the prompt for my credentials when I try to deploy a report.

Comment: Did someone else modify the AD directory entry you are using or the permissions on the Sharepoint site?

Comment: @EricHauenstein No, that wasn't the problem. The issue has actually just been resolved. Thanks for the response anyway :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution has been found!

Apparently something has gone wrong with my PC and I had to reconfigure my user accounts.

To do this go to Control Panel -> User Accounts

[image]

Then click on 'Manage User Accounts'. Go to the 'Advanced' tab and click on 'Manage Passwords'

[image]

Next, go to 'Windows Credentials' and change the credentials for your site or recreate them.